# php mysql special character escape

Tags: php, mysql

how to process php vars before trying to execute query?
e.g. i am trying to insert text with ",' but it query couldn't execute?
what is the best way to solve this with PDO class?

many thanks

Comment: You should refine your question more. What do you mean that you want to insert text with ",". Is it means that you want to insert all values to 1 coulmns seperated by , or any thing else

Comment: sorry for that. comma doesn't have any special meaning here. i want insert double and single quote characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps PDO::quote is what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: in my case this is a life savior

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at both [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). What's happening here is that a `'` is a special character, meaning MySQL will treat it as part of it's syntax, instead of treating it as a string like you want. `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string` will add a backslash `\` before all single and double quotes (and others) to make them not part of the MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_real_escape_string($string)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your incoming string so that ' and " will be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your PHP variables, not escape them.

```
$variable = "''''''''''''''''''";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?');
$sth->execute(array($variable));
```